# Using two properties for styling a featureCollection in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, style, feature-collection

I am attempting to overlay point data over some RS analysis and am happy to use the `ee.FeatureCollection.style()` function and the `styleProperty()` function.

I want to style both colour and point size dynamically and updated the featureCollection properties to have the format required.

I was hoping to get this to work, but no success.

```
Map.addLayer(updatedfc.style({
  color: {styleProperty: "statusl"},
  pointSize: {styleProperty: "canopy"}}), {},'conditionally styled');
```

Any idea how to style featureCollections based on multiple properties dynamically?

Answer (score 3):

Create featureCollection with properties

```js
var myfc = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([0, 0]), {status: 'CB0D0C', canopy: 10}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([0.0001, 0.0001]), {status: 'FF8819', canopy: 20}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([0.0002, 0.0002]), {status: '704B10', canopy: 30})
]);
```

Create a style object per feature:

```js
Map.centerObject(myfc,19)
Map.addLayer(myfc.map(function(f) {
    return f.set({
        'style': {
            color: f.get("status"),
            pointSize: f.get("canopy")
    }})}).style({styleProperty: "style"}))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works in general. It misses a set of brackets.